# JS DOM insertBefore() does not work properly

Tags: javascript, dom

I'd like to add a div in JS DOM before the footer of the website. However, it does not work (it puts the div *after* the footer).

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "Hello!";

const footer = document.getElementById('footer');

document.body.insertBefore(div, footer);
```

HTML:

```
<footer id="#footer">This is footer</footer>
```

I added the .js file before `</body>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id in the footer has an extra "#" so the Js selector doesn't work properly. Try removing it like:

```
<footer id="footer">This is footer</footer>
```